# Statue Park: Five

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Statue Park puzzle (originally constructed for the 2019 [24-Hour Puzzle Championship](http://forum.worldpuzzle.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=278), as part of a Tarot card themed set -- no prizes for guessing which rank this puzzle was).

Rules of Statue Park:

- Shade some cells of the grid to form the given set of pieces. Pieces may be rotated or reflected.
- Pieces cannot be orthogonally adjacent (though they can touch at a corner).
- All unshaded cells must be (orthogonally) connected.
- Any cells with black circles must be shaded; any cells with white circles must be unshaded.

[image: 6x15 Statue Park puzzle, with piece bank that looks like "FIVE."]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this does the trick:

> [image: soln]

Rough line of reasoning:

> The whole width of the puzzle is just enough to fit the four letters upright (putting any of them sideways won't work).  The problem is the last 2 x 1 piece.  This must go in the gap between two letters somehow.  
>  Observe that for the white squares to stay contiguous, the I must be the second letter.  It can't fit in the third space, and if it were in the first or fourth then it would close off a set of white squares.
>  With the I in place, we conjecture that the concave shape of the I's sides will permit the fitting of the 2 x 1 piece, combined with the empty space in the bottom half of the F.  A quick thought confirms that the 2 x 1 piece cannot possibly fit between any other two letters.  After trying to unsuccessfully fit the F in the leftmost spot such that there is room for the 2 x 1 piece, we can deduce that the F must be in the third place, to the immediate right of the I.  We can find the correct placement of the F and the 2 x 1 piece from there.  The rest is trivial.

Comment: That's correct, and exactly the intended logic!